# Is this possible to change from animate background

Tags: jquery, pagination, background, html-table, jquery-animate

I'm working on pagination, and I love jQuery animate, but one of things that I'm trying to solve that I can't figure out from tablesorter....

Please see the code [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eY8uH/767/),

```
$(function () {
    var $table = $('table'),
        checkboxColumn = 0;

    // checkboxes updates
    $table.find('tbody').on('change', 'input', function () {
        var $cell = $(this).closest('td');
        // only accept checkboxes in the first column
        if ($cell[0].cellIndex === checkboxColumn) {
            $cell.closest('tr').toggleClass('checked', this.checked);
            // update cache with checkbox state
            $table.trigger('updateCell', [ $cell[0] ]);
        }
    });

    $table.find('thead input').on('change', function(){
        var chk = this.checked;
        $table.find('tbody tr').each(function(){
            $(this).find('td:eq(' + checkboxColumn + ') input')
                .prop('checked', chk)
                .trigger('change');
        });
    });

    var headers = {};
    headers[checkboxColumn] = { sorter: false };

    $table.tablesorter({
        widgets: ['zebra'],
        headers: headers
    });
});
```

and please click checkbox on first column and you see is showing background when clicked, I was wondering if this possible to have slide animation background start from first column to end of columns when checked! and if is change to un-checked then slide animate of background from last columns to first column!

Comment: Can you please try to better clarify the behavior you're looking to create? Could you also provide what you've tried so far to create that behavior?

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that instead of showing color background road once checked, i like to show slide animate background color start from first column to end of next few columns once checked! And if unchecked, then do slide animate background from end of column to first columns instead disappear once. hope this clear what i'm trying to say.

Comment: It's not easy to do in a directional sense across multiple elements like you're wanting. The [jQuery Color plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) would likely be pretty helpful